# Counting the number of times an int appears in a file

Tags: c++, file, file-io, counter

I'm making a simple program that reads in a file and a value from a user, then counters how many time that value appears in the file. I've made this so far, it compiles fine, but when you input a number, nothing happens from there. I'm stumped. Sorry if this is very basic but I can't get past this.

This is what I have so far.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int hold,searchnumber, counter=0;

int main()
{ 

cout << "This program reads the contents of a file to discover if a number you enter exists in it, and how many times. \n";
cout << "What number would you like to search for? \n";
cout << "Number : ";
cin  >> searchnumber;

ifstream infile("problem2.txt");
if(!infile)
{
    cout << "Can't open file problem2.txt";
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
int sum=0,number;
infile >> number;
while (!infile.eof())
{
    if (number == searchnumber); 
    counter = counter += 1;
}
{
    cout << "The number " <<searchnumber << " appears in the file " << counter <<" times! \n";
    cin >> hold;
}

infile.close();
}
```

Comment: Others have answered the immediate problem, but here's a higher-level tip: when you are trying to write a program that does two things (e.g. get a number from the user, then scan a file), you should write and test those two functions *separately*, before you try to integrate them. That way, when something goes wrong, you'll know where to look (usually).

Comment: Do remember to factor in whether or your file would contain non numbers, big numbers etc or not. The corrected loop in simplistic form would work only for file containing valid integers. e.g. it would fail to find 2 1s in a file like this '1 33333333333333333333333333 1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This section contains two problems:

```
infile >> number;
while (!infile.eof())
{
    if (number == searchnumber); 
    counter = counter += 1;
}
```

The `while` condition is either true or false, and if it's true, it stays so forever, and it's likely why "nothing happens". There is NOTHING in the loop that changes the state of infile.

Combine the first two lines to:

```
while (infile >> number)
```

Then you at least run through the file.

Now, this:

```
    if (number == searchnumber); 
    counter = counter += 1;
```

Since there is a semicolon after the if-statement, you are basically saying "if it's the right number, do nothing" followed by updating the counter no matter whether you found the number or not. Remove the semicolon.

As usual, writing too much and too slowly.

Comment: Thank you so much! I understand your explanation, and why it works. Your help is so valuable, as was everyone else's replies. Will give you ticks once it lets me :)

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite loop at this line:

```
while (!infile.eof())
{
    if (number == searchnumber); 
    counter = counter += 1;
}
```

You open the file and read in the lines above it, but this loop just continues until you hit eof, but since you didn't read anything else in, as long as it wasn't eof when you entered the loop it will never exit.

Answer (score 0):

```
infile >> number;
while (!infile.eof())
{
  if (number == searchnumber); 
     counter = counter += 1;  
}
```

should be

```
while (infile >> number)
{
   if (number == searchnumber)
     counter += 1;
}
```

You need to read a number from the file each time before you compare. not simply do nothing in the file reading while loop.

BTW: you `sum` variable seems not used, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

1.

```
if (number == searchnumber); 
    counter = counter += 1;
```

should be

```
if (number == searchnumber) 
    counter = counter += 1;
```

2.
`sum` is unused.

Comment: @Drew Dormann remove the semicolon after `if (number == searchnumber)`

Comment: Ah!  My squinting is defective!